# how to reduce space after drawing graphs in RMarkdown using tikz

Tags: latex, r-markdown, tex, tikz

I am writing a RMarkdown presentation and in a specific slide (New subsection, please see below) I have 5 graphs and then too much space after that. This does not allow me to write more in that slide and moves the Text just below the title where there is no need for that. How to reduce that space?

[image]

````
---
title: name

author: name
        
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"

output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Szeged
    slide_level: 2
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    keep_tex: true

linkcolor: false
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


# Outline

## Outline

1. Item 1
2. item 2
3. Item 3

# New section

## New subsection

\small
\justify
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

More text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text tex. 

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, font=\footnotesize]
\put(-3,-20){
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{T}}] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{Y}}] (Y) at (1,0) {};
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (T)--(Y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, font=\footnotesize]
\put(45,7){
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{T}}] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{Y}}] (Y) at (1,0) {};
\draw[<-,shorten >= 1pt] (T)--(Y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, font=\footnotesize]
\put(94,62){
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{T}}] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{Y}}] (Y) at (2,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={above:{U}}] (U) at (1,0.5) {};
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (T)--(Y);
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(T);
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(Y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, font=\footnotesize]
\put(169,116){
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{T}}] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{Y}}] (Y) at (2,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={above:{U}}] (U) at (1,0.5) {};
\draw[<-,shorten >= 1pt] (T)--(Y);
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(T);
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(Y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, font=\footnotesize]
\put(245,171){
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{T}}] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{Y}}] (Y) at (2,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={above:{U}}] (U) at (1,0.5) {};
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(T);
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(Y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

Finally, more text in here.
````

My header.tex is:

```
\definecolor{mycolorlightblue}{RGB}{103,153,200}
\definecolor{mycolordarkblue}{RGB}{0,70,127}
% add packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
% remove 2nd section from header
\makeatletter
\beamer@theme@subsectionfalse
\makeatother
% change colour of lines
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=mycolorlightblue}
% text title
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=mycolordarkblue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=mycolordarkblue}
% text colour
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=mycolordarkblue}
% item colour
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=mycolordarkblue}
% define colour text
% \usebeamerfont{section title}\color{blue!70!green}\insertsection\par
% no header or footer on first page
\thispagestyle{empty}
% remove title slides at beginning of sections
\AtBeginSection{}
% add page counter to the footer
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(155,0){\makebox(0,0)[rt]{\includegraphics[]{ALL-ICONS.png}}}
  \end{picture}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `\put(94,62){...}` syntax you use. This won't place the image where the tikzpicture is, but will shatter them all over the frame.

Instead you can just let tex position the `tikzpicture`s for you:

```
\small
\justifying
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

More text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text tex. 


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, font=\footnotesize]
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{T}}] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{Y}}] (Y) at (1,0) {};
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (T)--(Y);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, font=\footnotesize]
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{T}}] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{Y}}] (Y) at (1,0) {};
\draw[<-,shorten >= 1pt] (T)--(Y);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, font=\footnotesize]
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{T}}] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{Y}}] (Y) at (2,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={above:{U}}] (U) at (1,0.5) {};
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (T)--(Y);
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(T);
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(Y);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, font=\footnotesize]
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{T}}] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{Y}}] (Y) at (2,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={above:{U}}] (U) at (1,0.5) {};
\draw[<-,shorten >= 1pt] (T)--(Y);
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(T);
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(Y);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45, font=\footnotesize]
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{T}}] (T) at (0,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={below:{Y}}] (Y) at (2,0) {};
\node[fill,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5pt,label={above:{U}}] (U) at (1,0.5) {};
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(T);
\draw[->,shorten >= 1pt] (U)--(Y);
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately still does not work for me. If I don't use \put(94,62){...}, I get one graph below the other, which is not what I want. I am using RMarkdown, so I have # New section ## New subsection, etc., not \begin{frame} \frametitle{New subsection} as you have there.

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues Did you remove the empty lines, like in my answer?

Comment: I didn't notice that. It is working now, thanks a lot!